# PassFactory.setNewPass is not a function, factory function not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

Can't seem to get this factory to work properly.
I'm trying to do the $http requests from a factory.
But I'm getting this error of: 
TypeError: PassFactory.setNewPass is not a function

Below is the code:
**Factory**

```
   (function () {
        angular
            .module("myApp")
            .factory('PassFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    /*
                var passFactory = {};
                passFactory.setNewPass = function (newpass, user) {
                    return $http.post('/password/' + newpass, user, function (response) {
                    });
                };
    */
                return {
                    setNewPass: function (newpass, user) {
                        return $http.post('/password/' + newpass, user, function (response) {
                        });
                    }
                };
            }])
    })();
```

**Controller**

```
 (function () {
        angular
            .module("myApp")
            .controller('PCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'PassFactory', setHome]);

        function setHome($scope, $location, PassFactory) {
            $scope.login = function (user) {
                if (user.newpassword == user.newpasswordconfirm) {


                    PassFactory.setNewPass(user.newpassword, user).then(function (response) {
                        $location.path("/");
                    });


                }
            };
        }
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `$rootScope` in controller factory function. Always make sure the the order in dependency have been injected inside `DI` array, in same sequence you should ask for their instance inside its factory function.

```
angular
 .module("myApp")
 .controller('PCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', 'PassFactory', setHome]);

//added $rootScope in 3rd place
function setHome($scope, $location, $rootScope, PassFactory) {
```